# What is the criteria for auto updating of iOS apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, software-update

For eg: for automatic iCloud backups, the iPhone must be connected to WiFi, plugged in and locked, and backup takes place once a day. Similarly, what would be the conditions for auto updating of iOS apps?

Answer (score 2):

The conditions for iOS apps auto update are mentioned below.

1. The app is purchased by you (or any family member if Family Sharing is ON)
2. In Settings ->iTunes & App Store, in the Automatic Downloads section, Updates is turned on.
3. If you want to update the apps on Cellular data, you can enable it on the same screen.